# PHP 5.5 upgrade to PHP 7 redis issues

Tags: php, redis

Good day,

We are currently running a fairly intensive system on PHP 5.5 connecting to a Redis database. The current setup has 6 Ubuntu 14.04 AWS instances dedicated to PHP and everything works fine. Due to some updated functionalities, we need to upgrade to PHP7 so I created a few Ubuntu 16.04 servers with PHP 7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1. We are using Predis (https://github.com/nrk/predis) to connect to the database but when I switch over to the 4 x PHP7 servers, I get random timeouts (not constant) - when these occur and because of the locking mechanism we have in place, the whole site becomes unresponsive for a few seconds.

So my question is mainly, has anyone ever got these issues? I think I have read some places that installing the phpredis extension helps, but that may have been a while back and I am not sure it's relevant here. Any insight on why I would need (or not) the extension would be useful.

I have copied the PHP settings from the old installation to the new one by comparing the INI and other configuration files but can post if needed.

Comment: are you using a elastic cache for redis db ?

Comment: We are using our own AWS instance for Redis - which works fine with PHP 5.5.9. I am really at loss as to what is causing it.